# Can dropped members be recovered in MKS?

Tags: version-control, mks, mks-integrity

My current client uses MKS for source control.

They have a policy where developers are not granted permissions to drop members.  This therefore prohibits us from doing moves etc., as well.

I've asked for the reasoning behind this, and I'm told it's because once you drop a member from MKS, you can't get it back.  Unlike in SVN where you can always recover from the history, apparantly in MKS once it's gone, it's gone.

Is this true, or is the client mistaken?

Is their an operation in MKS analogous to svn's delete operation?

Obviously not having full control over our source tree leads to problems with our codebase.  I'd like to know the facts before I challenge this practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can restore dropped members in MKS. 
**But** you must know the related archive file on the server. If the member was renamed and/or move in the past, this could be a very difficult task.

Comment: This is really a downside of MKS. It really sucks when it comes to dropping pj-files that do not use the project.pj convention.

Answer (score 2):

The command to add a dropped member again is "Add Member from Archive".
Or on the command line:

```
si addmemberfromarchive
```

As Martin pointed out, you need to know the location of the archive file on the central server.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Martin and @SzG I'd like to suggest making a reference list of member-to-archive and keep that updated.
Check the following command

```
si viewsandbox --recurse --xmlapi --sandbox=%SANDBOX% --includeDropped --fields=memberarchive,memberrev,workingarchive,workingrev,name
```

If you don't need working(archive|revision) you are well with `si viewproject`